# Does Elasticsearch make a copy of my data?

Tags: elasticsearch

I copied 1TB of data to a cloud server, then ran Elasticsearch on that folder. Things seemed to index great. However, I noticed that hard disk space went from 33% used to 90% used. So it seems Elastic must have copied the source directory? Can I now delete that 1TB of original data from that machine?

Comment: What do you mean by “ran Elasticsearch on that folder” ? Did you index the data into Elasticsearch ? It looks like disk space on your cloud server is 90% used but that data is NOT in Elasticsearch

Comment: Yes, I indexed the data into Elasticsearch. Before indexing, df -m reported only 33% disk space used. After, it was about 2x+ that. Right now I use Kibana and the Elastic http api to query the data. If I deleted the original folder, would those still function? (I guess I still don't know the internals of ES)

Comment: As long as you indexed the data already into ES you can remove the temporary folder where you copied data to if you no longer need it. Do NOT delete any ES indices from disk manually

Comment: did you check I/O on disk? or write thread_pool of elastic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `GET _stats/?human` you'll see lots of details from your cluster, like how much storage you are using or how many documents you have added. If you have all the data you want in your cluster and it's correctly structured, you can delete the original data. Elasticsearch has its own copy.

BTW by default you will get 1 replica if you have more than 1 node; so 1 primary and 1 replica copy of the data. If you have a single node there will only be the primary one.